# Trigger another function on dynamically created select change

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, triggers, onchange

Using datatables. It generated following selectbox dynamically with Javascript

[enter link description here http://content.screencast.com/users/TT13/folders/Jing/media/47ac4d39-5e96-415b-a51e-6d784ef18a3b/2012-02-11_0123.png](http://content.screencast.com/users/TT13/folders/Jing/media/47ac4d39-5e96-415b-a51e-6d784ef18a3b/2012-02-11_0123.png)

Firebug shows this piece of code for select box above

[image]

I tried to trigger `$('#check_all').click( function()` with following simple function. But it doesn't work. What Is there any mistake in code?

```
 $('select[name=list_length]').change(function(){
    if($('#check_all').prop('checked')) 
        $('#check_all').click();    
});

$('#check_all').click( function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        totalqt=0;
        $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', true);    
            doIt(this);             
        });
    }else{            
        $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);    
            doIt(this);             
        });
    }
    changeQt();     


} );
```

Comment: `$('#check_all').trigger('click');`?

Comment: @j08691 no.. same result

Comment: Shouldn't your if statement be `if ($('#check_all').is(':checked'))...`?

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on $('#check_all').click() and see if the code even gets there? It could be the handler isn't even bound. You might need `live('changed', function () {` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code like this.

```
function checkAllCheckboxes(isChecked) {
    if(isChecked ){
        totalqt=0;
    }
    $('.checkbox').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', isChecked);    
        doIt(this);             
    });
    changeQt();     
}

$('select[name=list_length]').change(function(){
    if($('#check_all').is(':checked')){
        $('#check_all').prop('checked', false);
        checkAllCheckboxes(false);    
    }
});

$('#check_all').click(function(){
    checkAllCheckboxes(this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see one thing that can be a problem in your code, but as you don't write about what exactly is failing, I'm not sure if this is the problem.

```
 $('select[name=list_length]').change(function(){
    if($('#check_all').prop('checked')) 
        $('#check_all').click();    
});
```

Here, you see if the checkbox is checked, and then you invoke a click event on it.

In the click event handler, you check again if the box is checked and iterate over the other checkboxes. However, the click event you invoke in the change event handler will change the checked state of the checkbox, and thus you get the oposite result of what's intended.

How do you like this solution?

```
var toggleCheckBoxes = function() {
    if($(this).prop('checked')){
        totalqt=0;
        $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', true);    
            doIt(this);             
        });
    }else{            
        $('.checkbox').each(function(){
            $(this).prop('checked', false);    
            doIt(this);             
        });
    }
    changeQt();     
}

$('#check_all').click(toggleCheckBoxes);
$('select[name=list_length').change(function(){
  if($('#check_all').is(':checked')){ toggleCheckBoxes(); }
});
```